# cakephp save with new association record

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have a trouble with save association data.
I want to add a new record to associated table.
For example, I have a User and Friend Model.

User Model has a [id, gender, age, hobby]
Friend Model has a [id, name, age, hobby]

My Table Data is below.

```
User|id|gender|age|hobby|
1   |1 |male  |24 |sport|

Friend|id|gender|age|hobby|
1     |1 |male  |24 |sport|
```

My Code is below.

```
$users = $this->Users->find()->contain(['Friends'])->where(['User.id' => $id])->first();
$data = $user->toArray();

$data['Friends'][1]['gender'] = 'male';
$data['Friends'][1]['age'] = 25;
$data['Friends'][1]['hobby'] = 'fishing';

$users = $this->Users->patchEntity($users, $data, 'associated' => ['Friends']);
$flag = $this->Users->save($users);
```

There is no problem when I edit existing data. But new data is not appended my database.
Anyone has any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your description says that Friend has a name, but your code is setting gender instead. Any chance this is simply a validation error because the name is blank?

Comment: Thank you for you answering! I checked it and there was no validation error. I think it  is impossible to append new data by using association data. Because there is no foreign key...

Comment: No, it's 100% possible. The save process understands the relationship and adds the foreign key from the parent record into the children as it goes along. If it's not working for you, it's a problem in your code. Capitalization is my next thought; while the name of the association is Friends, and that should be used in the `patchEntity` call, the key in the data array should be lower-case friends.

Comment: I apologize for my slow response and thank you again! As you said, a problem was in my code. I was revising code that was written by another person. And I didn't realize deleting process. The process was deleting new data I add. Thank you so much thinking together!